# Select 2 option is not selected using the search

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

in my project I use select 2, when I want to use the multi-selection search, I can't select when pressed, I can only select using the keyboard
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code, i hope to solve your issue.**

```js
$("#multiple").select2({
          placeholder: "Select a programming language",
          allowClear: true,
          minimumInputLength: 1
      });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Select2 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiple" class="js-states form-control" multiple>
  <option>Java</option>
  <option>Javascript</option>
  <option>PHP</option>
  <option>Visual Basic</option>
</select>
```